# How to insert empty row at the top of data table in csv with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv, datagridview

I'm making a desktop application using the windows form with C#, I stored uploaded csv data with data grid view, then I make a transpose feature in the application, but did not work well, because the row of index or row 0 does not included in transpose output file.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOULe.png)

So, I decided to add a empty row inside csv file at the top of data with this code

```
DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr1, 0);
```

I tried manually by insert empty row in csv and the application look like this
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ4WD.png)

How should I code to make application insert an empty data row at 0 and store it in data grid view looks like a picture above? so my transpose feature works well

here I wrote to store the data in data grid

```
        public DataSet ConnectCSV()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            string fileName = openFileDialogCSVFilePath.FileName;

            CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(fileName);

            ds = reader.RowEnumerator;
            dGridCSVdata.DataSource = ds;
            dGridCSVdata.DataMember = "TheData";
            return ds;
        }

 private void dGridCSVdata_Navigate(object sender, NavigateEventArgs ne)
        {

        }
```

here I wrote to read the data

```
public DataSet RowEnumerator
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == __reader)
                throw new System.ApplicationException("I can't start reading without CSV input.");

            __rowno = 0;
            string sLine;
            string sNextLine;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("TheData");
            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr1, 0);

            while (null != (sLine = __reader.ReadLine()))
            {
                while (rexRunOnLine.IsMatch(sLine) && null != (sNextLine = __reader.ReadLine()))
                    sLine += "\n" + sNextLine;

                __rowno++;
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                string[] values = rexCsvSplitter.Split(sLine);

                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = Csv.Unescape(values[i]);
                    if (__rowno == 1)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add(values[i].Trim());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Csv.CharNotAllowes(values[i]))
                        {
                            dr[i] = values[i].Trim();
                        }

                    }
                }
                if (__rowno != 1)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }

                ds.Tables.Add(Transposer.Transpose(dt));
                // transpose code
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (int u = 0; u < dt.Columns.Count; u++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(dt.Rows[i][u].ToString());

                        if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                        {
                            sb.Append(',');
                        }
                    }
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }

                File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Output.csv", sb.ToString());
            }
            __reader.Close();

            return ds;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: is my question still not clear? @Community